# MongoDB Realm vs. Stitch login times - why is Realm so slow?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, realm, mongodb-stitch, mongodb-realm

I've built a web tool using MongoDB databases hosted on Atlas, connected via [Stitch](http://stitch-docs-old.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/). From what I understand, Stitch is now depreciated and has been turned into [MongoDB Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/). So I tried to update my site, using the new Realm App instead of Stitch. While it does work, *anonymous* log-ins are now much slower for some reason. I did some quick testing, using the code suggested in the MongoDB documentation:

```
let t0 = performance.now()
app.logIn(Realm.Credentials.anonymous()).then(() => {
         let t1 = performance.now()
         db.collection('test').find({
                category: "test"
            }, {limit: 10})
        console.log("Login took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
    })
```

It takes me an incredible `1200 ms` to log in.

```
let t0 = performance.now()
app.auth.loginWithCredential(new stitch.AnonymousCredential()).then(() => {
            let t1 = performance.now()
            db.collection('test').find({
                category: 'test'
            }, {limit: 10}).asArray()
            console.log("Login took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
        })
```

With the old Stitch App, it usually takes under `20 ms` to log in.

Any ideas what's going on here or how to solve this? I do know that there is the possibility to first [authenticate a user](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/authenticate/) as described in their documentation, however I tried that and it's just as slow.

Is there actually a need to update to the new Realm App, e.g. will the old Stitch implementation stop working in the not too distant future? Any info on that would be appreciated ;)

**Update**: I did a bit more investigating, and it seems the reason why Realm is slower comes from the fact that logging in using `logIn(Realm.Credentials.anonymous()).then(() => ...` results in two Post requests, but using `auth.loginWithCredential(new stitch.AnonymousCredential()).then(() => ...` does the authentication and content download all in one request. With Realm I twice get a 500-700 ms TTFB waiting time, with Stitch that happens just once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating an application's backend from scratch with MongoDB Realm currently. I am using their Web SDK to authenticate using [email-password credentials](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/authenticate/#email-password). My round-trip performance averages around 600-800 ms.

[image: Chrome DevTools showing ~600 ms round-trip for Realm user auth]

For my application (using a Vue frontend), this is acceptable to me. I don't know what your requirements are, but you may want to try using the new SDK. Unfortunately, I'm encountering poor query performance with the GraphQL endpoint service Realm provides. According to [a thread I started on their forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/slow-graphql-querying-with-realm-27-sec-response-time-for-15-results/10801), their engineers are looking into it.

Comment: I get roughly the same times, maybe slightly slower. As I updated above, the reason might just be a different internal implementation of the same request/call. That's probably why Realm is working slower for me than the Stitch App.

Comment: I see. BTW, I was able to speed up my TTFB by removing several schema definitionss that my app was not using. Some of these schema definitions included 300+ fields and covered millions of documents. Now performance is acceptable for me (~1 sec round-trip queries).